# Installing Allegrograph on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, installation, ubuntu-14.04, allegrograph

I’m trying to install Allegrograph on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS using the below instructions from [here](http://franz.com/agraph/support/documentation/v4/server-installation.html)

However, I’m having problems. I have created the directory `/home/me/Allegrograph_4.14.1` and have myself as the owner. I then submit:

```
agraph-4.14.1/install-agraph`  /home/me/Allegrograph_4.14.1
```

However, I just get an error saying that `install-agraph` does not exist (I’m away from my computer to quote the exact returned error unfortunately but hope this is enough information).

I assume Allegrograph can be installed alongside mysql?

Comment: Could you add additional information as to which directory you extracted the tar.gz file? Apart from that did you add `./` before the agraph command?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling "agraph-4.14.1/install-agraph" from the correct directory. That would be the only reason I could think of why it can't find install-agraph. Additionally, you don't need to create the directory first. Just pass the script a usable path.